# Group communication system for .NET

Tags: .net, distributed, reliability

I need a transport mechanism, that guarantees total order broadcast of messages.

For example, I have three machines, A, B and C, that send messages: `A -> a0, a1, a2.. aN; B -> b0, b1.. bM; C -> c0, c1.. cK`. If one of the machines receives messages in some order `(a0, a1, b0, c0, b1, a2...)`, then all other machines will receive all messages in the same order!

And I need to use this thing from .NET environment. Is NServiceBus or Mass Trnansit can do the job for me?

Comment: do you mean if A, B and C send messages. Other machines will recieve the combined interleaved stream of messages in the same order?

Comment: No, all machines including A, B and C must receive all messages in the same order. Every message must be delivered to every participant, include sender. This problem is called atomic broadcast and already solved - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_broadcast. I'm looking for production ready .NET implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what it need is some sort of Distributed Queue with ordered guarantee, well maybe [DistributedQueue](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/recipes.html#sc_recipes_Queues) recipe of [Apache Zookeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/) can satisfied it

Answer (score 0):

Would not simply batching the message into a collection before sending fix your problem. So that when it is received, all receiver will iterate through the result set in the same order all the time.

Comment: This would work only in the case when all messages sent from one source. But in this case all messages already will be received in the predictable order (if transport like tcp is used). In my case all messages is broadcasted simultaneously from different sources and received by every participant, and every participant must receive messages in the same order.

Comment: The only way to achieve this without batching all the messages is to give each message some kind of ID or Sequence number. And have the receiving app to wait for all the result that is possible and then sort it once it get everything by the Sequence number/ID. What you are looking to do could be solved by re-sequencing. http://www.eaipatterns.com/Resequencer.html

Comment: If you really look at JGroup does it not do the same thing you are trying not to do. Which is to get all the messages first and then send them all in a sync manner from a single service meaning that each receiver will always get the FIFO effect no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't a product like TIBCO EMS solve these reliable realtime broadcast and delivery problems. These APIs have wrappers for most languages including .NET.

Comment: I think that I don't need enterprise messaging service, I need group communication system like JGroup, it's a completly different beast.

Comment: At this moment I implemented functionality that I need using centralized approach. There is a single server - sequencer, that receives all the messages in the system, and then delivers all messages to every participant in the same order. But this approach is not scalable nor fail safe.